# jQuery autocomplete: How to show an animated gif loading image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the jQuery [AutoComplete](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) plugin combined with ajax. Do you know how can I show a progress indicator while the ajax search is performed?

This is my current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#autocomplete-textbox").autocomplete('http://www.example.com/AutoComplete/FindUsers');
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="autocomplete-textbox" />
    <span class="autocomplete-animation"><img id="ajaxanimation" src="../img/indicator.gif")"/></span>
</div>
```

The FindUsers URL returns a user list in the content.

Comment: Can you show your actual markup/code that's being sent to the browser, i.e., without those Ruby/ASP/whatever `<% %>` markup?

Comment: There's still a `%>` in it; by accident, or is it that that's causing problems?

Answer (score 169, accepted):

autocomplete already adds the `ui-autocomplete-loading` class (for the duration of the loading) that can be used for this...

```
.ui-autocomplete-loading { background:url('img/indicator.gif') no-repeat right center }
```

Comment: When you use ThemeRoller, the loading gif related information gets stripped out of the download. http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6046

Comment: I think that this is a better solution than the accepted answer because it accounts for when no results are returned from the search.

Comment: and since the image is not in the themeroller download, get it from here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/smoothness/images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif

Comment: FWIW the animation does not work with a local (large) array based source (loaded async) for the autocomplete. Presumably because while the searching occurs, nothing else can do anything. For example: http://jsbin.com/EmikobU/1/edit

Comment: @ChrisKimpton : in jsbin that you've pasted the animation works while searching, I don't see any problem (using latest FF).

Comment: Thanks @Wookie88 - maybe I was using my works corp browser IE8 :(

Answer (score 48):

```
$("#autocomplete-textbox").autocomplete
(
search  : function(){$(this).addClass('working');},
open    : function(){$(this).removeClass('working');}
)
```

where CSS class working is defined as follow:

```
.working{background:url('../img/indicator.gif') no-repeat right center;}
```

**EDIT**

Sam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5073056/246429) is a better approach to address the problem

Comment: using the ui-autocomplete-loading class is more preferable as when there are no results returned this indicator stays on confusing the user

Comment: response: function(){} - Triggered after a search completes

Answer (score 1):

If no results   isn't works you can do this:

```
$("input[name='search']").autocomplete({
...,
select: function( event, ui ) {
action show image
}   
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
action hide image
}
```