# Jquery UI animation of loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, frontend

I need to do an animation of loading directly in the list of items, like this:[SnapShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1XUG.jpg)

I used `jQuery UI`, here the code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#cities").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
             var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
            $.ajax({
                url: "file.json",
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
           response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                var text = v.City;
                if(text && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text))){
                    return {
                        label: v.City,
                        value: v.City
                    };
                }
            }));
          });
        },


        search: function(event, ui){
            //$('#ui-id-1').addClass('ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front').show();            
        },
        open: function(event, ui) { 
          //  $('#ui-id-1').removeClass('ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front').hide();
        },


        close: function(event, ui) { 
           /*.......*/
        },
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.content.length) {   
                ui.content.push({label:"Not found"});
            } 
        }
    });
});
```

Html:

```
    <div class="wrap">

    <label for="cities">Cities: </label>
    <input id="cities">
    <ul  tabindex="0" id="ui-id-1" style="display: none;" ><li class="ui-menu-item "><div tabindex="-1" id='ui-id-3' class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Seeking</div></li></ul>

</div>
```

I've read that I can use `search` and `open` to manipulate with elements during loading of the source, but there is a problem:

I tried to use `.addClass` and `.show()` methods to display the list. It worked, but the element had the wrong position: It was on the top of page - styles for it didn't calculate at all.

How can it be fixed or are there any other ways?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you want this loading gif to appear as a list item upfront? How long do you normally anticipate a search taking to get results? This is why `minLenght` is an option. To help reduce the number of results by sending a larger term. Instead of "p" resulting in 1600 results, we send "pop", resulting in 24 results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489607/jquery-autocomplete-how-to-show-an-animated-gif-loading-image *autocomplete already adds the ui-autocomplete-loading class (for the duration of the loading) that can be used for this... `.ui-autocomplete-loading { background:url('img/indicator.gif') no-repeat right center }`*

Comment: I want  to display the animation during the loading of list, when search process is going, I just don't know how to place the animation into list

Comment: Here is a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2xj18jk9/ I will see if I can make it do more like what you;re suggesting in your image. Again, how much time do you anticipate the loading image to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that is a bit closer to what you showed in the image.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2xj18jk9/2/

**CSS**

```
.my-autocomplete-loading {
  width: 175px;
  background: white url('https://dmg98m9mr6pi1.cloudfront.net/RoR/images/wait_arrows.gif') no-repeat left center;
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cities").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      // Your Source Code
    },
    search: function(e, ui) {
      $("<span>", {
          class: "my-autocomplete-loading"
        })
        .html("Loading...")
        .insertAfter("#cities")
        .position({
          my: "left top",
          at: "left bottom",
          of: "#cities"
        });
    },
    open: function(e, ui) {
      $(".my-autocomplete-loading").remove();
    },
    minLength: 1,
    autoFocus: true,
    crossDomain: true
  });
});
```

So this makes use of `search` and `open`. See more:

- http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-search
- http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i found the 'dumb' way, but it works well, I just added a wrapper: 
$(document).ready(function() {

```
    $("#cities").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
             var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );

            $.ajax({
                url: "file.json",
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
           response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                var text = v.City;
                if(text && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text))){
                    return {
                        label: v.City,
                        value: v.City
                    };
                }
            }));
          });
        },
        search: function(event, ui){
            $('#ui-id-1').hide();
            $('#load').addClass('ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front');
            $('#load').css({
                position: "relative", 
                display:" block"}); 
        },
        open: function(event, ui) { 
            $('#load').removeClass('ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete ui-front').hide();
        },
        close: function(event, ui) { 

        },
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (!ui.content.length) {   
                ui.content.push({label:"Not found"});
            } 
        }
    });
```

html:

```
<span for="cities">Cities: </span>
<div class="wraper">
    <input id="cities">
    <ul  tabindex="0" id="load" style="display: none;" ><li class="ui-menu-item "><div tabindex="-1" id='ui-id-3' class="ui-menu-item-wrapper"><span class="preloader"></span>Loading</div></li></ul>
</div>
```